# How to initialize object with generic type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I tried to do this like:

```
export class MapperObject<V> {
    public obj: V = {};
}
```

It does not work. Further I need to fill object like:

```
this.obj[key] = "1";
```

Without initialization it invokes an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't do this in a type-safe way, because you don't know the  fields of `V` that are required. You can force initialization by using a type assertion, but it's not exactly safe:

```
export class MapperObject<V> {
    public obj: V = {} as any;
}
let m = new MapperObject<{ requiredProp: string }>();
m.obj.requiredProp // undefined even though it is required
```

The safe solution is to have a constructor that requires the passing of a default for `obj`:

```
export class MapperObject<V> {         
    constructor(public obj: V) {}
}
```